# $.cookie() exists but isn't acknowledged.

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm using jQuery Cookies to determine whether or not a user wishes to view the mobile site.

When the user, clicks the link 'View Full Site' they are taken to the homepage with a url parameter of: **fullscreen=yes**

```
$.extend({
   getUrlVars: function(){
      var vars = [], hash;
      var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

     for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
      {
         hash = hashes[i].split('=');
         vars.push(hash[0]);
         vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
     }

     return vars;
   },

   getUrlVar: function(name){
   }
});
```

If that parameter is set, then the cookie is created:

```
if ($.getUrlVar("fullscreen") != null) {
    console.log('creating cookie')
    var CookieSet = $.cookie('fullscreen', 'yesset', {path: '/'});
}
```

I also have a quick test on there to see if the cookie exists:

```
if (CookieSet == null) {
   console.log('Cookie Does Not Exist');

   // redirect stuff here

} else {

   // Do not redirect 
   console.log('Get In, it Exists!');
}
```

So, If the url parameter exists I am then taken to the home page, which does not redirect to the mobile site (Yes, I know this is a terrible way to do it, should be responsive - but the client wants it like that :(! ) and the console.log prints out:

```
 Get In, it Exists!
```

Which is great. Now this is the problem, When I click another link on the page. The console log briefly prints out: Get In, it Exists! but then quickly redirects to the mobile site. Which it shouldn't be doing.

Can anyone see why the cookie is been discovered but then ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check for your actual cookie, not just if the CookieSet exists (==null)?

```
if (($.cookie('fullscreen')!=null) {
   console.log('Cookie Does Not Exist');

   // redirect stuff here

} else {

   // Do not redirect 
   console.log('Get In, it Exists!');
}
```

maybe take a look at this: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/